# meaning of particle と in ためにと用意した

Tags: grammar, particle-と

What is the particle と means in ためにと用意した, and how is it different from ために用意した?

> 初撃{しょげき}の後{あと}の陽動{ようどう}のために**と**用意{ようい}した慧{けい}による「姫{ひめ}」の誘拐作戦{ゆうかいさくせん}。

"The strategy of kidnapping the "princess" by/which is done with the help of Kei, is prepared in order to make a diversion after the first attack."

Thank you!

Context:

> 慧「まったく・・・そのやたら無謀なところは昔とまったく変わらないな、お前は・・・」
>
> 雪隆「それで、どうする？　協力してくれるか？」
>
> 慧「…それは」
>
> 俺の問いに慧は…。
>
> 初撃の後の陽動のためにと用意した慧による『姫』の誘拐作戦。
>
> 最初から第９の騎士に奪還させることが目的ではあったのだが、るる姉たちは何も知らずによくやってくれた。
>
> おかげで『姫』は争奪戦無しで転がり込み、俺は闘技場に残った筆頭騎士三人を葬る事が出来た。

More context: As far as I understand the kidnapping of 姫 itself was 初撃の後の陽動のために, because before the kidnapping the speaker/narrator with 慧's help made a sneak attack and in order to not fall under suspicion, right after the attack 慧 kidnaped 姫, and while the sneak attack and the kidnapping 慧 was disguised, so nobody except narrator knew who is it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between 「～～ために」 and 「～～ためにと」 can be very subtle at times; nevertheless a difference does exist.

To use 「～～ために」, the speaker needs to be 100% certain of what the reason for an action is.  The action-taker may be either the speaker himself or another person.  If the latter is the case, the speaker already possesses enough information to determine what the reason is.

To use 「～～ためにと」, the speaker may or may not be 100% certain of what the reason for an action is.  The action-taker would generally not be the speaker himself.  The use of 「と」, though it is called the quotative paricle, does not necessarily require an actual quote of a statement.  From my experience with Japanese-learners, this is what seems to confuse them.  It is perfectly natural and correct to use the quotative 「と」 and 「って」 to express what the speaker merely thinks or believes would be the opinion of either the general public or a specific individual.  In other words, you do not have to have heard it said by someone.

In the phrase (it is not a sentence) 「[初撃]{しょげき}の[後]{あと}の[陽動]{ようどう}のためにと[用意]{ようい}した[慧]{けい}による「[姫]{ひめ}」の[誘拐作戦]{ゆうかいさくせん}。」 , the speaker, who is clearly [雪隆]{ゆきたか}, may or may not have actually heard 慧 say that 慧 prepared his strategy for the reason of 初撃の後の陽動のため.  The reason may well be 雪隆's conjecture.

If I were asked to rephrase 「～～のためにと用意した」 for a better understanding, I would suggest inserting immediately after the 「と」, words like 「[思]{おも}い/思って」 or 「[考]{かんが}え/考えて」.  The important thing is that in this case, the person who 思う or 考える is 慧, not the narrator.

Comment: This question would be perfect without the commentary on Japanese learners.

Answer (score 3):

It's the quotative particle と, i.e.

> 「初撃の後の陽動のために」と用意した慧による「姫」の誘拐作戦。

The actual meaning isn't much different, but gives a slight nuance that 「初撃の後の陽動のために」 are somebody else's words (e.g. 慧's), not the speaker/narrator's. I would need more context to see if this is done for a specific reason.

Comment: I guess the one who made this strategy is the speaker/narrator, well maybe I'm mistaken, so added the context.

Comment: @DarkAkira, yes, you seem to be right. This is still not quite enough for me to understand the narrator's motives. Does he have a hidden motive to kidnap the 姫, and therefore gives 初撃の後の陽動のために as a fake reason?

Comment: as far as I understand the kidnapping of 姫 itself was 初撃の後の陽動のために, because before the kidnapping the speaker/narrator with 慧's help made a sneak attack and in order to not fall under suspicion, right after the attack 慧 kidnaped 姫, and while the sneak attack and the kidnapping 姫 was disguised, so nobody except narrator knew who is it.

Comment: Sorry, and while the sneak attack and the kidnapping 慧 was disguised, not 姫 of course.