# Meaning of にと思って in a sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I've been thinking about this for a few days but I still can't figure out what this means. Sorry if this is really beginner-like!

I was wondering what this particular part in a sentence means: にと思って. Example sentence is:

> ［これは私の新しいレシピだ。］君のお弁当**にと思って**作ってきたんだ。

(the first sentence is only there for context, the second contains what I want to ask for.)

Please help! I appreciate any answers.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21680/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16000/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14475/9831

Answer (score 4):

I assume you know how to use ～と思って, which is "..., thinking ～". Try to read it like this:

> 「君のお弁当に」と思って作ってきたんだ。

Everything before the quotative-と is a quote (in this context, what he thought). So 君のお弁当に is the content of his thoughts, and it makes sense on its own. The particle に has many functions, one of which is denoting a purpose. It's like English "as ～" or "for ～".

> - プレゼントに人形を買いました。 I bought a doll as a present.
> - 何に使うの？ What do you use it for? / What is it for?

Thus the sentence means simply "I made it for/as your *bento*/lunch.", or more literally, "I made it thinking '(It would be) for your *bento*.'"